# Management/Documentation of Role-Based Authorization in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, authorization, resharper

I'm new to a project and have inherited a site that uses role-based authorization.  There are a lot of `Authorize` attributes on the methods in the code - for example:

```
public class MyController:Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I want to sort of have authorization definitions for each of these roles like:

- Manager - can edit/delete an order
- Admin - can edit/delete users

I was wondering if there is any special MVC/Visual Studio/ReSharper function that can produce a list of methods that have particular roles or if compiling somehow generates documentation somewhere that I can glance at.  I have looked around for something to help with no luck.

Comment: This is a phenomenal question. Whether with `AuthorizeAttribute` or custom authorization attributes, I have seen this need arise in multiple ASP.NET MVC projects - and am struck that I don't recall anyone (myself included) ever asking whether a tool or straightforward mechanism to help document/manage authorization exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

I am not aware of a Visual Studio or MVC feature or a plugin (including ReSharper) to do what you want directly; but Visual Studio and .NET provide the basic building blocks to do it - e.g. regular expressions and reflection.

### VS Find in Files (Using Regular Expressions)

**Overview**

The easiest (if not the most elegant) way to do what you want is to simply search your project or solution with Visual Studio's **Find in Files** dialog (*Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) using a regular expression...

[image: VS Find in Files Using Regular Expressions]

..., which will return results like the following:

```
Find all "(?<=\[[HttpGet]+\]\s+(\[[A-Za-z_]+\]\s+)*)(public\s+)(?!(class|interface)\s+)[A-Za-z_<>]+\s+[A-Za-z_]+\s*\(", Regular expressions, Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, "*.cs"
  C:\Users\me\Source\Repo\Solution\Controllers\Controller.cs(21):        public List<SomeType> Action1() {
  C:\Users\me\Source\Repo\Solution\Controllers\Controller.cs(30):        public List<Foo> Action2() {
  C:\Users\me\Source\Repo\Solution\Controllers\Controller.cs(38):        public List<Bar> Action3() {
  C:\Users\me\Source\Repo\Solution\Controllers\AnotherController.cs(46):        public List<Bar> ActionA(int n) {
  C:\Users\me\Source\Repo\Solution\Controllers\AnotherController.cs(78):        public List<Baz> ActionB() {
  C:\Users\me\Source\Repo\Solution\Controllers\YetAnotherController.cs(35):        public SomeOtherType ActionAlpha() {
  C:\Users\me\Source\Repo\Solution\Controllers\YetAnotherController.cs(51):        public List<SomeType> ActionBeta(int n) {
  Matching lines: 7    Matching files: 3    Total files searched: 32
```

Here I searched for public methods with `[HttpGet]`.  (Also note that I did this in VS 2013, [which uses standard .NET regular expressions for Find in Files unlike previous versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).)

**Applied to Your Case**

For your case centered on `[Authorize(Roles = "<role>"]`, I would start with the following regular expression for all methods with the attribute...

```
(?<=\[Authorize\(Roles = "[A-Za-z]"\)\]\s+)(public\s+)(?!(class|interface)\s+)[A-Za-z_<>]+\s+[A-Za-z_]+\s*\(
```

...and a narrower variant of it for methods with the attribute and a specific `Roles` argument (e.g. `"Admin"`):

```
(?<=\[Authorize\(Roles = "Admin"\)\]\s+)(public\s+)(?!(class|interface)\s+)[A-Za-z_<>]+\s+[A-Za-z_]+\s*\(
```

Tweaks to the regular expressions above will probably improve your results (e.g. character classes like `[A-Za-z_]`, `Roles *= *"` instead of `Roles = "` etcetera); but they should provide a good start at least; I checked them against `AuthorizeAttribute` with various `Roles` arguments.

If you have trouble understanding or tweaking the above regular expressions, MSDN's [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) and other online resources should prove helpful.

### Other Possibilities

A couple other ways to approach what you want that come to mind (among many others) are:

- Writing a quick tool that uses .NET reflection.
- Using [NDepend's CQL](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-features).

### *Edit*

Per my comment on your question that it is simply phenomenal, I realized that I had not stopped to do a basic search to challenge my experience. :/

It turns out that a Jigar.Net article entitled [Authorization in ASP.Net MVC using XML Configuration](http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent324.aspx) describes a cool, different way to manage/document authorization - *proactively* using a dedicated XML configuration section like the following...

```
< controllers > 
   < controller  name ="Admin"> 
     < roles > 
       < role > Admin </ role > 
       < role > Edit </ role > 
       < role > View </ role > 
     </ roles > 
     < actions > 
       < action  name ="Index"> 
         < roles > 
           < role > Admin </ role > 
           < role > Edit </ role > 
           < role > View </ role > 
         </ roles > 
       </ action > 
       < action  name ="Edit"> 
         < roles > 
           < role > Edit </ role > 
           < role > Admin </ role > 
         </ roles > 
       </ action > 
       < action  name ="Admin"> 
         < roles > 
           < role > Admin </ role > 
         </ roles > 
       </ action > 
     </ actions > 
   </ controller > 
   < controller  name ="Home"> </ controller > 
</ controllers >
```

...paired with supporting code.  (The article also underscores that a database is of course an alternative to an XML config section.)

I plan to consider this question further and look for other approaches & tools; hopefully someone can answer with even greater insight; but this is what I quickly found once I tried. :}